# Another input radio is effecting my jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got a jquery statement that shows/hides image upload input based on the user's radio selection.

I now have an issue where another radio selector component is started to interfere with the below. If any radio selector from the other section is pressed. All the file inputs disappear.

The below radio selector culprit

```
<div class="background-choices">
  <h3>Color</h3>
    <label>
    <input id="background-choice-input" type="radio" name="color" value="Blue" />
      <img src="https://www.colorhexa.com/000080.png">
    </label>
</div>
```

My jquery statement

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    $('.imagehide').hide(); // Hide all images here
    if ($(this).attr('id') === '1choice') {
      $('#img-image1').show();
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') === '2choice') {
      $('#img-image1').show();
      $('#img-image2').show();
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') === '3choice') {
      $('#img-image1').show();
      $('#img-image2').show();
      $('#img-image3').show();
    } else {
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So change the generic `input[type="radio"]` selector to something more specific which targets only the radios you want...

Comment: THANK YOU, sorry for the nub question decided to learn jquery to compliment my html and css :)!!!!  slowly learning! changed to my radio class now it only affects the right one.